# What do the dwarfs do with all of the diamonds that they mine?

Tags: plot-explanation, snow-white-and-the-seven-dwarfs

In *Snow White and the Seven Dwarfs*, I don't really understand what the dwarfs do with the precious jewels that they mine because they don't have separate houses or even a very big house.

Considering how untidy and dirty they are too, they don't have a cleaner! Surely they would make a lot of money from these jewels? Also how do they pay for their house if they do not sell them? Don't know whether I'm looking into this too deep.

Comment: This isn't a proper answer but you may find this enlightening & amusing: http://www.cracked.com/blog/fan-theory-shady-disney-diamond-cabal-finally-exposed/

Comment: Perhaps they use them to edge their mining tools.

Comment: "Don't know whether I'm looking into this too deep." Firstly, you are, and secondly, that's totally fine. That's pretty much what movies Stack Exchange is for.

Comment: So... er... do you believe that real-life diamond miners are rich?

Comment: I don't know much about mining but considering that the dwarves had piles of diamonds sitting in the mine, I'm not sure.

Comment: @DavidRicherby I believe the owners of a diamond mine might well be comfortably off. Especially if fortuitous, random, geological processes have rendered the diamonds in their mine both cut and polished!

Comment: In the originating fairy tale(s), I think it's considered likely that the "dwarfs" were a reference to child labor in the mines. The few that survived to adulthood often had stunted, warped appearances.  But I'm guessing you were looking for logic internal to the Disney movie.

Answer (score 59):

It's never explained and, it's possible, they do it *just because it's their job*.

There's even a line in the song "Heigh-ho"...

> We dig up diamonds by the score
>
> A thousand rubies, sometimes more
>
> **Though we don't know what we dig 'em for**
>
> We dig dig dig a-dig dig

It's also worth noting that they don't care about mine security since **they leave the key to the mine vault right outside the vault door on a hook.** In other words, they just like to dig the diamonds for no real reason.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the feedback I will slightly improve my question

Comment: Agreed.  They are just an archetype of a mythological creature.  Dwarves are associated with mining and metalworking.  You see this in Tolkein as well as the Snow White fairytale.

Comment: But Tolkien Dwarves create vast underground cities and trade their ores and products with other communities.  They certainly have purposes and reasons for their mining.

Comment: @M.A.Golding, because Tolkien was "creating a world." The difference is that in the Disney adaptation of *Snow White and the Seven Dwarves* the purpose for the dwarves' mining occupation is largely irrelevant to the story (as is their language, racial history, social conventions, etc). Just because the story Disney told didn't require additional details, it doesn't mean the archetype doesn't hold.

Comment: Heigh-ho also explicitly says that they dig just because they like to, and that it isn't a "get rich quick" scheme.  This is the right answer.  They don't hire a cleaner because they clearly don't value cleanliness, they don't make a lot of money from jewels because they don't sell them, and they don't pay anyone for their house, because who would they pay anyway?  They probably built it themselves in the middle of nowhere.

Comment: @GrandOpener I'm not sure why you'd say "this is the answer" in the comments of another answer. If you disagree, why not post your own?

Comment: @AJFaraday .... I think he's saying that this answer is the correct answer, and adding a couple of supporting comments.

Comment: _"leave the key to the mine vault right outside the vault door on a hook"_ - Potentially to keep animals out?

Comment: Don't think animals have much use for precious gems

Comment: Plot twist: The only reason you would leave a key next to a door like that is if you were locking it to keep something _inside_ the door from getting out.  Perhaps they are not mining "diamonds and jewels" after all?

Comment: Plot twist: The key is magic and if you touch it, you are cursed to become a dwarf, mining for eternity.

Answer (score 8):

They hoard them. Dwarves love gold/diamonds/precious elements just for themselves, and not for what it can buy them.

This obsession to mine and hoard these elements is unlike someone who sees diamonds etc. as a commodity or currency and what these things can do for them. In themselves, these things have no real value besides looking pretty. Or of course you have industrial use for them, for example. Dwarves in western myth have a natural and innate love for diamonds and/or other precious metals/stones which results in coveting them for the sake of coveting them, having possession of them alone (kind of like a drug addict and the drug they are addicted to). These dwarves are no different. They mine and hoard because they can't help themselves.

(The irony in this is the fact that dwarves seem to be attracted to elements that *others* find valuable (because of their high trade in or market value), which to me, seems to show a kind of tendency to hoard something that others like, and this fact may actually be the real cause of their obsession, which is something to consider as well. But that's a topic for another question.)

Comment: What dwarves like tends to be things others find valuable, but they don't like *everything* that others find valuable.  They like what they like.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if this is correct, but thinking on other adaptations to Snow White, we see the queen as a dictator that takes everything from everybody, maybe it is their payment so no one meddles with them and their life. Also they probably own the house and get their food from the forest, they don't have a luxurious life which also means that they live with what they can find.

Comment: It would be great to see excerpts of those adpatations to help support your answer!